# Accessing elements in the shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

Is it possible to *find elements inside the Shadow DOM* with python-selenium?

**Example use case:**

I have this `input` with `type="date"`:

```html
<input type="date" name="bday">
```

And I'd like to click *the date picker button* on the right and choose a date from the calendar.

If you would inspect the element in Chrome Developer Tools and expand the shadow-root node of the date input, you would see the button is appearing as:

```
<div pseudo="-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator" id="picker"></div>
```

Screenshot demonstrating how it looks in Chrome:

[image]

Finding the "picker" button by id results into `NoSuchElementException`:

```
>>> date_input = driver.find_element_by_name('bday')
>>> date_input.find_element_by_id('picker')
...
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
```

I've also tried to use `::shadow` and `/deep/` locators as suggested [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/):

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name=bday]::shadow #picker')
...
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
>>>
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name=bday] /deep/ #picker')
...
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
```

---

Note that I can change the date in the input by sending keys to it:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('bday').send_keys('01/11/2014')
```

But, I want to set the date specifically by choosing it from a calendar.

Comment: Are you using the last version of ChromeDriver? Chromedriver supports Shadow DOM since v2.14 (2015-01-28).

Comment: @f.cipriani yes, the latest (2.14). Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a _functional_ example of the use case?

Comment: @SiKing I've been using [the one from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date) (sorry :)). Thanks. Note: you would need to switch to an iframe before accessing the date input.

Comment: Works only in Chrome, not in FF. :( Are you looking for python-only answer?

Comment: @SiKing if you would provide an answer using other selenium bindings it can also help - I'll try to mimic the solution and see if I can reach that picker button with python bindings. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way to access the shadow root of native HTML 5 elements.

Not useful in this case, but with Chrome it's possible to access a custom created shadow root:

```js
var root = document.querySelector("#test_button").createShadowRoot();
root.innerHTML = "<button id='inner_button'>Button in button</button"
```

```html
<button id="test_button"></button>
```

The root can then be accessed this way:

```
 var element = document.querySelector("#test_button").shadowRoot;
```

If you want to automate a click on the inner button with selenium python (chromedriver version 2.14+):

```
 >>> outer = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#test_button").shadowRoot')
 >>> inner = outer.find_element_by_id("inner_button")
 >>> inner.click()
```

**Update 9 Jun 2015**

This is the link to the current Shadow DOM W3C Editor's draft on github:

http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/

If you're interested in browsing the [blink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(layout_engine)) source code, [this is a good starting point](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/dom/&sq=package:chromium&rcl=1433907179&type=cs).

Comment: This makes total sense. You are basically saying that this new chromedriver feature: [Issue 852: Support shadow dom in chromedriver.](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=852) is basically about custom elements with shadow DOM inside, correct?

Comment: That's correct. Chromedriver is just a wrapper on the top of the browser API. Since Chrome doesn't allow scriptable access to user-agent shadow DOMs (they can be styled tho), the same is true for selenium.

Comment: great answer, but it has some downsides for nested shadow roots elements check my answer below

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer has a drawback, many times the shadow host elements are hidden withing shadow trees that's why the best way to do it is to use the selenium selectors to find the shadow host elements and inject the script just to take the shadow root:

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

#the accepted answer code then becomes 
outer = expand_shadow_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#test_button"))
inner = outer.find_element_by_id("inner_button")
inner.click()
```

To put this into perspective I just added a testable example with Chrome's download page, clicking the search button needs open 3 nested shadow root elements:
[image]

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

driver.get("chrome://downloads")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('downloads-manager')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_css_selector('downloads-toolbar')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element_by_css_selector('cr-search-field')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)

search_button = shadow_root3.find_element_by_css_selector("#search-button")
search_button.click()
```

Doing the same using the accepted answer approach has the drawback that it hard-codes the queries, is less readable and you cannot use the intermediary selections for other actions:

```
search_button = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("downloads-toolbar").shadowRoot.querySelector("cr-search-field").shadowRoot.querySelector("#search-button")')
search_button.click()
```

Comment: His only works if the Shadow DOM is open, correct? Otherwise the .shadowRoot will return null. Is there a way to access the closed Shadow DOM? Writing a Chrome Extension wouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Pascal .shadowRoot returns the Shadow DOM, open and close is just in the Inspector GUI, if something returns null and you expect that element to be a shadow root you might have selected the wrong element

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In this blog post, it exemplifies the fact that closed Shadow DOM returns NULL (https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af).

Comment: @Pascal Actually  you might be right I was unaware of this open/close modes

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know either. I found out during this Selenium test case, and I'm trying to find a way around it. Tks anyways.

Comment: @Pascal Yeah, it seems that you need to inject this before that page JavaScript runs `Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354352/selenium-how-to-inject-execute-a-javascript-in-to-a-page-before-loading-executi

Comment: Or you could make an extension that runs that before and then run Selenium with extensions see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48564477/1577343

Comment: Yeah... I'll probably go with the extension. Thanks so much

Comment: Not that easy... couldn't get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954383/override-element-prototype-attachshadow-using-chrome-extension

Comment: @Pascal Glad to see that some one figured it out that is a different context, good to learn something upvoted both