# Selenium: How can I get the link for downloads that started automatically?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using selenium to automate some downloading tasks, but some pages start the downloads automatically and I need to know the links of those downloads during or after the download and the link is not available in the page.

How can I get the URL of the files that started downloading automatically?

Comment: Is what you are looking for not in the `onload` event of the page?

Comment: @JeffC I was unable to find where the URL is in the HTML or the JS code, maybe its generated on server side and the JS code just fetches it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Chrome to run your selenium scripts you can just navigate to the chrome://downloads/ and get the latest download file's URL.

Or you can fire a Ctrl+J keyboard action to the browser using java robot classes and open the tab.

(Chrome downloads page is a html page and you can capture elements in it)

Comment: The `chrome://downloads` changed and the page contains a lot of shadow root elements to work around that check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911799/accessing-elements-in-the-shadow-dom/37250674#37250674

Comment: I'm assuming that there is no way to do it and this is just a workaround, which is unfortunate.