# how to querySelect from shadow root that was created with closed mode

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I have a shadow root that was created with `mode: closed`

```
<session-expiration-popup>
  #shadow root (closed)
  <div class="custom-element-root">
    something
  </div>
</session-expiration-popup>
```

Is there any way to `querySelect` something from this shadow root?

I tried

```
const el = document.querySelector('session-expiration-popup')
el.shadowRoot.querySelector(".custom-element-root");
```

however, it is not working cause `shawRoot` param is `null` for `mode: close`

Also, I tried to `el.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })` but it's also the wrong way that leads to the exception (shadow root exist for el element).

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. It's the intended behaviour and the purpose of a **closed** Shadow DOM.

The only workaround is to overload the `attachShadow()` method and then create an open Shadow DOM instead when the method is invoked.

[Example in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54954525/4600982)