# How to use javascript to select the button inside a shadow root

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, shadow-dom

I am curious to see how this situation can be solved.
In browser, I am seeing the following content (note the button is in highlight)
[image]
However, the selected the shadow root `document.querySelector("ow-356ai793a").shadowRoot` lost the entire content within the div element `<div shell-wrapper="" data-spot-im-direction="ltr"></div>`, as shown here
[image]

How can I select the button `<button role="button" data-spmark="show-more" data-spot-im-class="load-more-messages" aria-label="Show more comments" data-openweb-allow-amp="true" type="button" class="Button__button--11-4-6 Button__primary--11-4-6 Button__isEllipsis--11-4-6 Button__hoverBackground--11-4-6 spcv_load-more-messages"><span class="Button__contentWrapper--11-4-6"><span class=""><span>Show More Comments</span></span></span></button>` within the shadow root then?

Answer (score 0):

You can access anything inside the shadow root from JavaScript only if it have `open` [mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode).

If the `shadowDOM` was created with `element.attachShadow({ mode: "closed" });`, you can not access the `shadowDOM` with JavaScript.

So, now if your shadowDOM is `open` hen you could use following.

```
const shadowRoot = document.querySelector("ow-356ai793a").shadowRoot;
const button = shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-spmark='show-more']");
```

Comment: That will result in button being null. You saw that the entire div is missing, as I mentioned above, right? It is the same issue as in @Victor L.'s answer above.

Comment: Given the element (I am not the creator of the shadow root element), how to tell its mode?

Comment: It looks from the pictures I pasted above, the element IS open?!

Comment: Please checkout this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56020162/9640177 . If you are not getting anything inside shadowRoot means it is closed.

Comment: If you think it is open, first print the shadowRoot then you can see whether all elements are accessible from JS or not.

Comment: I've already showed in the second picture about the `shadowRoot` element and the entire div containing the button is missing.

Comment: That means your blob is closed and no way to access elements inside it using JS

Comment: Did you see `shadow-root (open)` in the first picture I pasted?

Comment: Please create sandbox so that I can work out on your code. Thanks.