# how to click on an element within shadow-root(closed)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: 1]

I'm trying to click on this element with selenium but it cant find since its with in a shadow-root. It's an extension button that does something when you click it. the shadow root is closed

here is my code

````
root = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="button-holder help-button-holder"]'))
    # Locate the extension button within the shadow root
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "solver-button")))
    button = root.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@tabindex='0'][@title='Solve the challenge'][@id='solver-button']")
    button.click()```
````

Answer (score 1):

Since Selenium implemented CDP protocol API, `shadow-root` with `closed` state can be overridden with `open` state on page load.

You just need to override `Element` class prototype method `attachShadow` and evaluate script on new document before page load.

[How to override Element properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54954525/20292589)

[How to executed script on load via CDP Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68532593/20292589)

**Example of code:**

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': """
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
"""})
driver.get(url)
closed_shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="button-holder help-button-holder"]')
shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', closed_shadow_host)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke click on an element within ***shadow-root(closed)*** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) as `@hayatoito` (creator of Shadow DOM) in his [comment](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/378#issuecomment-179596975) clearly mentioned:

> The original motivation of introducing a closed shadow tree is *`"Never allow an access to a node in a closed shadow tree, via any APIs, from outside"`*, AFAIK. Like that we can not access a node in the internal hidden shadow tree which is used in `<video>` element, in Blink.

> In fact, I designed a closed shadow tree in such a way. If there is a way to access a node in a closed shadow tree, it should be considered as a bug of the spec.

> I think it's totally okay to have an API to allow an access in the layer of Chrome apps or extensions.
> However, for a normal web app, I think the current agreement is *`"Never allow it"`*.

> If we allowed it, that means we do not need a closed shadow tree. Just having an open shadow tree is enough, I think.