Override Element.prototype.attachShadow in Chrome Extension's content script
We're trying to test chrome extension using selenium 4. Extension creates a shadow root (closed) using content scripts. We need to somehow verify elements inside of it.
I've seen these questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77243136/4142087 But this doesn't work for us, as extension operates in its own context.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54954525/4142087 This is basically the same (it says, that chrome extension's content scripts operate in their own context).

Having all the necessary permissions for tests, how could we make shadow root open or access closed.
[UPDATE] Not a direct solution, but since we currently don't need to make some actions like clicks, reading data can be enough. If chrome inspection window can read internal html, could we dump html and verify it manually? For example using beautiful-soup

You can send DOM.getDocument command with depth:-1,pierce:true and get the entire DOM tree including the closed shadow roots. You can also use DOM.querySelector + DOM.describeNode to get just this element.

works, thanks! Could you format this to answer, so I could approve it?

It'd be better if you post your own answer with the actual code.

@woxxom not sure I can post exact code, but maybe simplified version of it will be ok, thanks again :)
