# Get element under #shadow-root for Angular camera plugin

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to emulate a shutter click on a camera plugin on angular called @capacitory/angular.

Here's what the HTML looks like when inspected.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjxSf.png)

This is how I am trying to fetch it in python selenium

Option 1:

```
shutter = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('pwa-camera-modal-instance').shadowRoot.querySelector('pwa-camera')")
shutter.execute_script("document.getElementByClassName('shutter').click();")
```

Option 2:

```
shutter = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('pwa-camera-modal-instance').shadowRoot.querySelector('pwa-camera')")
shutter.find_element_by_class_name("shutter").click()
```

If I am able to find how to fetch it I might be also be able to also click the save icon here [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tivIj.png)

However, the following didnt work. So i am not able to get the click the shutter and save the photo. Really need this to have coverage on uploading pictures.

I already referred to this source:
[Does anybody know how to identify shadow dom web elements using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141681/does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing elements in the shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911799/accessing-elements-in-the-shadow-dom)