# Shadow-dom support for selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom

I am working on an automation project which uses shadow DOMs extensively.
I use the `execute_script` function to access shadow root elements.

For example:

```py
root = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector(".flex.vertical.layout").shadowRoot')
```

Then I use the root element to access the elements within.
Since we have shadow root elements at many levels, this is annoying me a lot.
Is there any better solution to access elements within shadow root elements?

I am using Chrome 2.20 driver.

Comment: I read once in the release notes (around a year ago) that Chrome binary driver started supporting shadow-dom in selenium.  Not sure what was really implemented.

Comment: Apparently so - though the question is what bindings are available to let you use it. Certainly no friendly API (friendlier than the OP's code) within the Selenium code AFAICT.

Comment: I gave an example in the answe how to tackle the nested shadow roots

Answer (score 5):

By googling I found another workaround for this problem - which is using the "`/deep/` combinator".

For example, I was able to access all the shadow roots elements with

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body/deep/.layout.horizontal.center')
```

This will have access to the element with the compound class name `layout horizontal center` regardless of the number of shadow roots it has.

But this only works for the chromedriver and `/deep/` is a deprecated approach.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

The WebDriver spec still [doesn't have anything specific to say](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) about Shadow DOM.

Nor the Selenium [project pages](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki) - which is understandable, as they closely follow the spec. Yet there is [some low-level code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Shadow%20DOM%22&type=Code) in existence.

So, the short answer is: **no,** there is no special support in the spec, in Selenium's WebDriver API or implementation code at present.

Yes, the capability seems to exist in ChromeDriver 2.14 (as a wrapper around Chrome). However, as far as I can tell there are no Selenium or WebDriver-level bindings to let you use it.

But for more detail and possible workarounds, see also: [Accessing Shadow DOM tree with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920167/accessing-shadow-dom-tree-with-selenium), also: [Accessing elements in the shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911799/accessing-elements-in-the-shadow-dom), and especially: [Finding elements in the shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28682814/954442)

Comment: Thanks Andrew for valuable references.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to have this automated on Chrome I came up with an inelegant solution of recursively searching through each shadow dom explicitly using:

```java
driver.executeScript(scriptToRun, cssSelector);
```

Here's the javascript (passed as a string):

```js
function recursiveSearch(element, target) {
    let result = element.querySelector(target);
    if (result) { return result; }
    let subElements = element.querySelectorAll("*");
    for (let i = 0; i < subElements.length; i++) {
        let subElement = subElements[i];
        if (subElement && subElement.shadowRoot) {
            let result = recursiveSearch(subElement.shadowRoot, target);
            if (result) return result;
        }
    }
}
return recursiveSearch(document, arguments[0]);
```

Since the contents of a `shadowRoot` might be empty initially one can use `driver.wait` and `until.elementIsVisible` to avoid returning a null element.

Async example:

```java
return await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(await driver.wait(async () => {
           return await driver.executeScript(scriptToRun, cssSelector);
       }, timeOut)));
```

### Alternatively

My previous solution was to traverse the elements with shadowdoms explicitly, but is less autonomous. Same as above but with this script:

```js
let element = document.querySelector(arguments[0][0]);
let selectors = arguments[0].slice(1);
for (i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
    if (!element || !element.shadowRoot) {return false;}
        element = element.shadowRoot.querySelector(selectors[i]);
    }
return element;
```

Where `selectors` would be something like:

```
['parentElement1', 'parentElement2', 'targetElement']
```

### Sidenote

I found that running my automation tests on Firefox Quantum 57.0 doesn't suffer from hidden shadow doms, and any element can be found with a simple:

```java
driver.findElement(searchQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write extension methods to operate on `IWebElement` to expand the root as below.

```java
public static class SeleniumExtension
{
    public static IWebElement ExpandRootElement(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        return (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver)
                .ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    }
}
```

You can use the above extension method to traverse through the element's hierarchy to reach the element of interest.

```java
By downloads_manager_ShadowDom= By.TagName("downloads-manager");
By downloadToolBarShadowDom = By.CssSelector("downloads-toolbar");
By toolBarElement = By.CssSelector("cr-toolbar");

IWebElement ToolBarElement = driver.FindElement(downloads_manager_ShadowDom).ExpandRootElement(driver).FindElement(downloadToolBarShadowDom).ExpandRootElement(driver).FindElement(toolBarElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use often that you may create a function, then the above becomes:

```
def select_shadow_element_by_css_selector(selector):
  running_script = 'return document.querySelector("%s").shadowRoot' % selector
  element = driver.execute_script(running_script)
  return element

shadow_section = select_shadow_element_by_css_selector(".flex.vertical.layout")
shadow_section.find_element_by_css(".flex")
```

on the resulting element you can put any of the methods:

> ```
> find_element_by_id
> find_element_by_name
> find_element_by_xpath
> find_element_by_link_text
> find_element_by_partial_link_text
> find_element_by_tag_name
> find_element_by_class_name
> find_element_by_css_selector
> ```
>
> To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):
>
> ```
> find_elements_by_name
> find_elements_by_xpath
> find_elements_by_link_text
> find_elements_by_partial_link_text
> find_elements_by_tag_name
> find_elements_by_class_name
> find_elements_by_css_selector
> ```

**later edit:**

Sometime the shadow host elements are hidden withing shadow trees that's why the best way to do it is to use the selenium selectors to find the shadow host elements and inject the script just to take the shadow root: :

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

#the above becomes 
shadow_section = expand_shadow_element(find_element_by_tag_name("neon-animatable"))
shadow_section.find_element_by_css(".flex")
```

To put this into perspective I just added a testable example with Chrome's download page, clicking the search button needs open 3 nested shadow root elements:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

selenium.__file__
driver.get("chrome://downloads")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('downloads-manager')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_css_selector('downloads-toolbar')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element_by_css_selector('cr-search-field')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)

search_button = shadow_root3.find_element_by_css_selector("#search-button")
search_button.click()
```

Comment: shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
What does this line do? Why arguments[0] instead of element?

Comment: @Vincent that line of code (`return arguments[0].shadowRoot`) is in JavaScript, and arguments[0] is the way to pass values from python to JavaScript when executing driver.execute_script , the value is that of the element indeed but this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may use `IJavaScriptExecutor`?

```java
IWebDriver driver;
IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecutor.ExecuteScript('yourShadowDom.func()');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works in all browsers, but for me
`::shadow` works fine in chromedriver 2.38 For example:

```
div::shadow div span::shadow a
```