# Why does targeting shadow dom elements fail at the 5th element?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, google-chrome

Recently asked how to target elements in chrome settings here: [How to edit chromes search and homepage with selenium/python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263863/how-to-edit-chromes-search-and-homepage-with-selenium-python)

I was told I should use 'shadow dom' elements, so I went ahead and figured out how to do that.

I was able to successfully target the search field on chrome's download page using shadow dom inception, but when applying almost identical logic/code to target the to open a specific page or set of pages on chrome://settings/ , python returned an error

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"settings-on-startup-page"}

How do I solve the problem?

---

Eduard Florinescu commented: "when you usually have also dynamic content and more than 3 shadow elements one into another it makes impossible automation."
here: [How to handle elements inside Shadow DOM from Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium)

I'm hoping someone can explain the limitation or workaround here?

HERE IS EXAMPLE CODE THAT WORKS FOR TARGETING THE SEARCH FIELD ON CHROMES DOWNLOAD PAGE

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/John/Desktop/Documents/selenium/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")

#define inception function
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root


#start doing inception
driver.get("chrome://downloads")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('downloads-manager')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_tag_name('downloads-toolbar')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element_by_tag_name('cr-toolbar')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)

root4 = shadow_root3.find_element_by_css_selector("cr-toolbar-search-field")
shadow_root4 = expand_shadow_element(root4)

root5 = shadow_root4.find_element_by_id("searchInput")

root5.send_keys('test')
```

HERE IS EXAMPLE CODE THAT DOE NOT WORK FOR TARGETING THE OPEN A SPECIFIC PAGE OR SET OF PAGES RADIO BUTTON.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/John/Desktop/Documents/selenium/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")


#define inception function
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root


#start doing inception
driver.get("chrome://settings/")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('settings-ui')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_tag_name('settings-main')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element_by_tag_name('settings-basic-page')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)

root4 = shadow_root3.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-section")
shadow_root4 = expand_shadow_element(root4)

root5 = shadow_root4.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-on-startup-page")
shadow_root5 = expand_shadow_element(root5)

root6 = shadow_root5.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-radio-group")
shadow_root6 = expand_shadow_element(root6)

root7 = shadow_root6.find_element_by_name("4")

root7.click()
```

AS YOU CAN SEE, BOTH CODE SNIPPETS ARE ALMOST IDENTICAL IN SYNTAX AND STRUCTURE, YET THE SECOND DOESN'T WORK.

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\Documents\selenium\projects\startpage_domain_test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/John/Desktop/Documents/selenium/projects/startpage_domain_test/startpage_domain_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/John/Desktop/Documents/selenium/projects/startpage_domain_test/startpage_domain_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    root5 = shadow_root4.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-on-startup-page")
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 430, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 659, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"settings-on-startup-page"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just have to recursively traverse the elements with `shadowRoot`s.

Try it like this:

```
def find_in_shadow_dom(css):
  return driver.execute_async_script("""
    const traverse = e => {
      let el
      if(el = e.querySelector('""" + css + """')){
        arguments[0](el)
      }
      [...e.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(e => e.shadowRoot).map(e => traverse(e.shadowRoot))
    }
    [...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(e => e.shadowRoot).map(e => traverse(e.shadowRoot))
    arguments[0](null)
  """)

input = find_in_shadow_dom('#searchInput')
input.send_keys('testing')
```

**Edit: Notes for settings page..**

```
control = find_in_shadow_dom('[label="Open a specific page or set of pages"]')
# don't forget to scroll into view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", control)
control.click()
```

Comment: I tried using this code snippet and it works sometimes, but trying to target the 'Open a specific page or set of pages' radio button on chrome://settings/ returns the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click' when I try to click it with:                                                      input = find_in_shadow_dom('span[label="Open a specific page or set of pages"]')   input.click()

Comment: Similar issue when trying to use this function to target its parent container: input = find_in_shadow_dom('controlled-radio-button[label="Open a specific page or set of pages"]')  -> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (631, 1418)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such limit to access the shadow element. You should be good to access them until you provide the correct shadow tree elements.

**Refer to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow/56381495#56381495) for detailed explanation. It's informative and detailed..**

Here is the js that you can pass and return the element

```
input = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('downloads-toolbar#toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-toolbar#toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-toolbar-search-field#search').shadowRoot.querySelector('input#searchInput')")
input.send_keys('testing')
```

*Screenshot:*
[image]

Comment: I was able to copy paste this code and get it working with the search bar on chrome://downloads, but when I try to use the same basic structure to click the 'add' button on chrome://settings/searchEngines I get an error. Why does it work in the first example but not the second?

Comment: url = "chrome://settings/searchEngines"
driver.get(url)
input  = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-main#main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-section').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-search-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-animated-pages#pages').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-subpage').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-search-engines-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-button#addSearchEngine')")

input.click()

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

Comment: Not sure which element you are targeting. I was able to point to the element successfully as shown in the screenshot.