# Finding xpath of shadow dom elements with robot framework

Tags: selenium, xpath, polymer, robotframework, shadow-dom

I'm writing automated UI tests using Robot Framework with python.  I'm testing a Polymer application that uses the shadow dom Robot's standard libraries don't seem to be able to locate elements in the shadow dom using xpath.

I've been sorting through selenium's repo/overflow/internets and polymer's repo/overflow/internets and haven't found the intersection of a solution for using robot with python (the selenium workaround isn't that graceful either).  I was hoping someone had run into this issue with this specific framework that might be willing to share a solution (or note that there's not one).

Test Case

Wait Until Page Contains Element xpath=(//html/body/some-root-shadow-dom-element/input)

This of course results in an error because the shadow dom is not put into the main document of the DOM tree.

Comment: Not in a single xpath like that because they're in different documents. [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367383/why-does-targeting-shadow-dom-elements-fail-at-the-5th-element#57368078) that might help but it uses css not xpath

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow/56381495#56381495) for the solution and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Open the browser console and type this into the console:

```
dom:document.querySelector("apply-widget").shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("div)
```

Make sure to hit enter after so it will be ran.