# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message. selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[this is html code and structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDnAo.png)

**I get 2 words but it returns a blank list, so I used the WebDriverWait function but I still have an error**

**I saw all the possible options on the internet but could not fix it**

**How fix??**

this is code --->

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\chromedriverr\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://bankofgeorgia.ge/ka/currencies")
teams = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabs"]/bog-universal-tabs//div/iron-pages/div[1]/bog-currencies-list//div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]')))
print([i.text for i in teams])

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: "I still have an error" but you've neglected to post the error you are getting.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel this is --> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message. selenium (python)

Comment: @JustinEzequiel posts title is error

Comment: Pasting your xpath into DevTools' search text shows zero (0) hits.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Can you explain me better?

Comment: Weird page. I can only search for the `bog-app` tag. I am unable to search anything within the said tag.

Comment: See if the data [here](https://bankofgeorgia.ge/api/currencies/page/pages/5c0a361ff85d2d574073cf30) is what you need.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel How did you find it?

Comment: DevTools, Network tab.

Comment: This page uses Shadow DOMs. In order to use Selenium to locate these specific elements, you need to use JavaScript execution. [See this question on how it was done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141681/does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv)