# Selenium Python - Unable to locate element - It this website blocked ? (shadow DOM)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill this form with selenium in python:  https://ing.ingdirect.es/app-login/

Using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser.get('https://ing.ingdirect.es/pfm/#login')

WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#aceptar'))).click()

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ing-uic-native-input_0').send_keys('xx')
```

But I get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: #ing-uic-native-input_0
```

[inspection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atqln.png)

I have tried unsuccessfully to find frames and other ways to find the element: xpath, id, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you bring that page up, you have to click the "accept cookies" button to move on.  Are you doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, here's your solution [Does anybody know how to identify shadow dom web elements using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141681/does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv)

you're trying to get element with shadow DOM webelements.

or try to use install pyshadow library:

```
pip install pyshadow
```

and use like that:

```
from pyshadow.main import Shadow
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://ing.ingdirect.es/pfm/#login')
shadow = Shadow(browser)

shadow.set_explicit_wait(20, 5)
shadow.find_element("#aceptar").click()
element = shadow.find_element("#ing-uic-native-input_0")
element.send_keys('xx')
```

don't like using all of the wrappers, but seems like shadow elements require some wrapper work and guys from google already did it.

second, to skip the step with clicking on accept cookies, there's quite good way to store cookies of that step and replace them each time:

run that first time:

```
import pickle
cookies = browser.get_cookies()
with open("cookies.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), f)
```

then remove and run that each next time:

```
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    browser.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: This is perfect. I was not aware of the shadow DOM web elements.  Also, the cookies trick is nice. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Antonio more over, you can skipp login step with cookies feature as well and move to the page like already logged in user

Comment: thanks @Vova !   I still need to learn how to do it. That's next step :) !

Answer (score 0):

First, accept cookies once in the beginning of all tests steps.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#aceptar")))
accept_cookies = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#aceptar")
accept_cookies.click()
```

Second, after accepting cookies a user is redirected to https://ing.ingdirect.es/app-login/
There is no `#ing-uic-native-input_0` CSS element.
As an example, if you are looking for `Número de documento` use:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("input")
```

Also, before making an input use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located`. It should be more reliable.

Comment: There shadow dom elements, have you worked with them?Honestly, I’ve not

Comment: I have got it to send if you want to look. It's still kind of ugly though.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
browser.get('https://ing.ingdirect.es/app-login/')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#aceptar'))).click()
root1 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > ing-app-login-sca-es')))
root1 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', root1)
root2 = root1.find_element_by_css_selector('div > div.wrapper-login > ing-orange-login-sca-es')
root2 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', root2)
root3 = root2.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginSteps > ing-uic-login-sca-es-step-credentials')
root3 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', root3)
root4 = root3.find_element_by_css_selector('#credentialsForm > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > ing-uic-login-sca-es-el-input')
root4 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', root4)
root4.find_element_by_css_selector('#ing-uic-native-input_0').send_keys('xx')
```

Here's what it would look manually. It looks pretty bad getting the shadow root manually for 4 elements. Also your login url is pretty hard to login.

Comment: Thanks. I was not able to make it work, though.