# Receiving error in selenium (javascript) when opening shadowRoot

Tags: javascript, selenium, shadow-dom

I am setting up the first automated tests for a web app I'm working on, and have hit a state I don't understand.

It is a browser app, so I start a very simple static server:

```js
    import http from 'http';

    let serve = serveStatic(path);
    server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        var done = finalhandler(req, res);
        serve(req, res, done);
    });
```

During my testing, I receive an error message `HTTP method not allowed`

```js
let options = new firefox.Options();
options.headless();
let capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.firefox().set('acceptInsecureCerts', true);
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .withCapabilities(capabilities)
    .build();

await driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:3030/index.html');
let tab = await driver.findElement(state.By.css('ps-tabpanel'));
tab = await tab.getShadowRoot(); // HTTP method not allowed
```

On a hunch, I changed this to an `HTTPS` connection

```js
import http from 'https';
```

In this case I receive a very different error

```js
await driver.get('https://127.0.0.1:3030/index.html');
// Reached error page: about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https%3A//127.0.0.1%3A3030/index.html&c=UTF-8&d=%20
```

So my main question is, what am I doing wrong to access the `shadowRoot` using Javascript Selenium?

For reference

- mocha + selenium + firefox
- gitpod environment
- have an earlier test that simply verifies I can connect to `example.com` just to prove the connection is working.

Comment: Switching protocols from HTTP to HTTPS is irrelevant to fixing the HTTP method error.

Comment: Any suggestion on what might be relevant?

Comment: Does your server run?

Comment: It finds the html element, so yes. (also can browse it manually, and find text on the page)

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to work around the error, I switched to the javascript executor. This raised a different error message (cyclical object).

This led me to a different stackoverflow question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67223939/1961413

According to that answer, this is a known defect in the GeckoDriver/Firefox.

Based on that I switched to the ChromeDriver/Chrome, and was able to find the ShadowRoot.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver

```js
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
await driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:3030/index.html');
let tab = await driver.findElement(state.By.css('ps-tabpanel'));
tab = await tab.getShadowRoot();
```