# InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am a beginner with Robot framework with Chrome. I have no problems using it but on a website developped by my colleagues, I cannot input text in a specific textfield (error message: InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state). Here is my code:

```
*** Settings ***    
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***
Create normal activity

    wait until page contains element  //*[@id="root_pagemashupcontainer-2_mashupcontainer-88_ptcsbutton-225"]
    click element    //*[@id="root_pagemashupcontainer-2_mashupcontainer-88_ptcsbutton-225"]
    wait until page contains element  //*[@id="input"]
    input text    //*[@id="input"]  ActivityName
```

If I inspect the textfield here is what I have:

[Element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ25o.png)

I have tried :

- Zooming out to make sure the element is fully visible
- waiting a few seconds between each action
- This element's xpath is "//*[@id="input"]" . It is not the only element with that Xpath so I have tried using the full Xpath and CSS of that element and the ptcs-texfield element
- Using Katalon Recorder. It works on other web pages but on that web page, the clicks are recorded but not the text typing.

Nothing has worked.

Comment: If you look up towards the top of that HTML you will see the element is inside of a `shadow-root`.  You need to access that first before interacting with the element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141681/does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: @JD2775  Many thanks! I got it working with this:
`input text    dom:document.querySelector("#root_pagemashupcontainer-2_mashupcontainer-88_mashupcontainer-207_ptcstextfield-216").shadowRoot.querySelector("#input")  Hello`

Now I've got a dropdown list which values are inside of a shadow-root. How can I select a value?

Comment: @BryanOakley The last one.