# What is the correct way to correctly identify an object via Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am currently dabbling in Python in combination with Selenium. I can't get any further at one point.

Enclosed you can see three screenshots. At https://www.easycredit.de I already click on the button (1). After that I get to the next page. I would like to click this button (2) now. In Screenshot 3 you can see the location in the source code.

```
# link to Chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'econ-button btn  btn-primary')
button.click()
```

The error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".econ-button btn  btn-primary"}
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.79)
```

Here are my questions:

1. hy does it not work with this code?
2. How do you find out with which procedure it works best in a case like this?
3. How do you choose whether to identify an element by XPATH, ID etc.?

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Thanks

Comment: Your website contains `shadow DOM` or also called as `shadow root`, which could not be located with regular selenium ways. You need to first open the `shadow root` and then access the elements. Here is a thread that could guide you in shadow roots. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141681/does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`econ-button btn  btn-primary` are actually 3 class names.
`By.CLASS_NAME` gets only single class name parameter.
To work with locators containing multiple class names you can use `By.XPATH` or `By.CSS_SELECTOR`.
As for me both the above methods are good, each of them having several cons and pros.
So, here you can use

```py
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.econ-button.btn.btn-primary')
```

Or

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='econ-button btn  btn-primary']")
```

Generally, you can use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `By.XPATH`. No need to utilize `By.ID` or `By.CLASS_NAME` since they are actually internally immediately translated to `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `By.XPATH` :)
Some people preferring to use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` while others prefer `By.XPATH`.
As I mentioned previously, each of the above 2 methods having cons and pros.
For example you can locate elements by their texts with XPath only. XPath supports locating parent element based on their child nodes.
On the other hand XPath will not work so good on Firefox driver while it works perfectly on Chrome driver etc.
**UPD**
The locator for the second `nein` radio button can be:

```py
"//label[.//input[@data-econ-property='kreditdaten-beduerfnisfragen-flexibilitaetGewuenscht'][@value='radio3']]"
```

So, Selenium click can be done with

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[.//input[@data-econ-property='kreditdaten-beduerfnisfragen-flexibilitaetGewuenscht'][@value='radio3']]").click()
```

And so on with other buttons

Comment: This is working. Thank you! Can you please check the website again and give me a hint how to click the radio buttons? In the code there is a "::before" and the element ist called "<span class="econ-radio__icon"></span>"

Comment: I can help you with this too, no problem. But It would be better if you accept the answer here and open a new question for this issue since this is actually a new question. Also, I can't currently understand what radio button are you asking about, there are several radio buttons there, so to give unique locator / solution i need more information.

Comment: Just the first radio button is activated from beginning. All others are not selected and I want to select all of them with "nein".

Comment: OK, I have added the second radio button locator / click command. You need to learn how to find effective locators. There are a lot of tutorials for that

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>Zu den finanziellen Angaben</kbd> is a dynamic element. So to click element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.econ-button.btn.btn-primary[value='Zu den finanziellen Angaben']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='econ-button btn  btn-primary' and @value='Zu den finanziellen Angaben']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this but the code from Prophet is also working and a bit more easy. Why do you think the way with WebDriverWait is better?

Comment: @edstrinova using `WebDriverWait` is needed in most cases since after many actions it takes some time to elements to be loaded, rearranged and fully rendered before you will be able to click them.