# Chrome DevTool cannot find XPath generated by its own

Tags: xpath, google-chrome-devtools

Why Devtool cannot even find its own Xpath?

Windows 10, Latest Chrome Version 104.0.5112.102 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Clicked plus sign for a new tab. New tab went to default google search.

Please see screenshot [image]

1. right clicked on the search field, selected Inspect. This opened DevTool, and highlighted the element.
2. right clicked on the highlighted element, select Copy, XPath.
3. Control + F in Devtool, pasted the Xpath into the search box.
4. there was no match: 0 of 0 !!!

It was not a highlighting issue as some other posts reported.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Apparently it doesn't work inside Shadow DOM. FWIW `id("input")` is a better xpath.

Comment: Were namespaces involved? In XPath 1.0 paths to namespaced elements will usually involve a namespace prefix that has to be declared before the path can be executed.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I think you are right. It must be Shadow DOM. When I posted the question, I wasn't aware of this new feature. After your hint, I read more articles. I believe it is due to Shadow DOM. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wOxxOm suggested it was due to the  tag was in a Shadow DOM. When I posted the question, I wasn't aware of this new feature. After his/her hint, I read more articles. I believe it is due to Shadow DOM.

[image]

I present this as a temporary answer, and leave for more knowledgeable folks to provide an acceptable answer.

There are good resources on Stack Overflow about Shadow DOM, for example this one
[does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141681/does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv)