# Automated testing of the Shadow DOM

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, shadow-dom

Has anyone been able to use Selenium or similar tools to test web pages that use the Shadow DOM?

When I attempt to record tests, it will not recognize the elements and play back.

Is there an easy way to do this? We would like for non-technical users to be able to create tests

Comment: There's some tutorials they could do like [katalon studios](https://dzone.com/articles/automation-testing-of-shadow-dom-elements-with-kat). Is there an easy way to do this with [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139212/shadow-dom-support-for-selenium). At a glimpse probably not out of the box with the tools available for recording. For creating the tests it might be possibly if you hide the technical implementation behind [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/).

Comment: Which type of Shadow DOM exactly? Your code trials please.

Comment: Maybe this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37388179/4600982