# Selenium method to set date using Native mobile OS date pickers

Tags: android, ios, selenium, datepicker, native

We are using Katalon a test automation IDE to develop our test automation framework and scripts. Our application uses Ionic framework and is built in a webview. For the date and time entries the developers are calling the native mobile OS pickers. We need to be able to set/select date and time in each of the mobile Operating Systems.

I have tried to use Chrome(for Android) and Safari(for iOS) to find the elements for the native date time pickers with no success. Using Katalon with a Java/Groovy Selenium script I can retrieve the value and click the element but I am unable to find or work with the date time pickers in either Mobile OS.

I expected to be able to find an Xpath for the element but even after switching out of Native mode I cannot interact with the code.

My expected is

1. Open the date/time picker from the mobile application.
2. Select the date/time. This will include navigation to previous/next month and previous/next year. Once on the correct month year select the day.
3. On enter the value I expect to enter the value in the picker edit field.

Comment: Native date pickers are usually achieved using the Shadow DOM. A little bit of googling hasn't gotten me any authoritative sources on how to interact with the Shadow DOM with Selenium, but starting here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36139212/3092298

Comment: There is this post on [Katalon and Shadow DOM](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/shadow_dom_elements_testing.html#what-is-shadow-dom).